# Should i use XML Serialization with large file

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xsd.exe

I have a set of very large XML data with XSD. One xml might be up to 300MB.

I need to move data from XML into SQL Server.

I found that Microsoft has serialization library to map xml into objects
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx

The problem I am worrying about is, when it maps the xml into object, will it load all the data into memory? If it does, it seems I cannot use it.

So is XmlTextReader the best way for my case like read line by line and store data into database.

Comment: Is this migration a one-time thing or you need to do this regularly?

Comment: How complex is the XML data structure? If it's simple, then there are some workarounds.

Comment: @conqenator

XML file will always come in daily... i need to write a service to move data from XML into database. so it is regularly

Comment: @Ron Klein

hmm.... what do u mean complex???

it might up to 10 level nest elements..

Comment: is the xml eventually a list of the same object? like a list of customers? if so, then I think you can use a reader to parse one object at a time, and insert it to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in .NET, XML serialization reads everything into memory at one time.

A more memory-efficient approach is to use a System.Xml.XmlReader to read the content line-by-line.